# Fast replacement of 2 matrix in python

Tags: python, arrays, string, text, nlp

Sorry if it's a simple question, I'm new in python. I have an string (array of words) and a 2 dimensions of words which I'm going to replace them one by one as something like follow:

```
str="Jim is a good person"
# and will convert to:
parts=['Jim','is','a','good','person']
```

and a 2 dimensions array which each dimension is a array of words that can be replaced with an element with same index in parts. for example something like this:

```
replacement=[['john','Nock','Kati'],
             ['were','was','are'],
             ['a','an'],
             ['bad','perfect','awesome'],
             ['cat','human','dog']]
```

result can be something like this:

```
1: nike is a good person
2: John are an bad human
3: Kati were a perfect cat
and so on
```

Actually I'm going to replace each word of a sentence with some possible words and then do some calculation on the new sentence. I need to achieve all possible replacement.

Many thanks.

Comment: Sounds good. Do you have a question here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) might be the best choice for creating all of the combinations that you're looking for.

Let's use your replacement list as a starting point for what could work. A way to get all the combinations you're looking for could look something like this

```
from itertools import product

word_options=[['john','Nock','Kati'],
             ['were','was','are'],
             ['a','an'],
             ['bad','perfect','awesome'],
             ['cat','human','dog']]

for option in product(*word_options):
    new_sentence = ' '.join(option)
    #do calculation on new_sentence
```

Each option that is being iterated through is a tuple, where each element is a single choice from each of the individual sub-lists of the original 2D list. Then the `' '.join(option)` will combine the individual strings into a single string where the words are separated by a space. If you were to just print `new_sentence`, the output would look as follows.

```
john were a bad cat
john were a bad human
john were a bad dog
john were a perfect cat
john were a perfect human
john were a perfect dog
.
.
.
Kati are an perfect cat
Kati are an perfect human
Kati are an perfect dog
Kati are an awesome cat
Kati are an awesome human
Kati are an awesome dog
```

Comment: That's what I wanted, Thank you Joe